# OllyDbg how to see the main thread (all memory in the cpu)

Tags: ollydbg, memory, thread

I can't figure out how to see more than the [CPU - main thread, module  ]
in the CPU window.

Sometimes when I jump to an address the title changes just to [CPU - main thread]
and now I can see all of the memory in the program (including the PE header)

For comparison:
[CPU - main thread]

[image]
[CPU - main thread, module  ]

[image]

How do I switch between these two? When I press "view threads" it only shows me one executing thread, when I click it, it shows me the [CPU - main thread, module] which is not what I want.

Strange.

Comment: I suspect it shows "module XXX" when the `EIP` is in the range of the specified module, and just "main thread" otherwise. Try checking `EIP` value against the memory map.